# Do the amino groups in EDTA deprotonate first, in contrast to amino acids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, carbonyl-compounds, amines

We know that in amino acids, carboxylic acid groups deprotonate first than the amine groups. For example, in alanine, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a,\ce{COOH}} = 2.34$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a,\ce{NH3+}} = 9.69$ according to [this page](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/chem104A_S07/Lecture_Notes_104/lect27c.html).

But according to the structures of EDTA as searched from [Google](https://www.google.com.ph/search?safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=SJ4TWu6mJMi98QWk0rC4CQ&q=disodium+edta+structure&oq=disodium+edta+structure&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i5i30k1.88207.95411.0.95632.33.22.8.3.3.0.140.2171.7j13.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.31.2273.0..0i10k1j0i8i30k1j0i24k1j0i30k1.110.b7vZtx6Xz3A#imgrc=koWizya-CSge3M:), and from this extract from p.325 of Analytical Chemistry, 8e by Christian, et al.:

> At sufficiently low pH, the nitrogens can also be protonated and this diprotonated EDTA can be considered a hexaprotic acid. However, this occurs at a very low pH and EDTA is almost never used under such conditions.

the hydrogens of these amino groups seem to be deprotonated first before those of the four carboxylic acid groups. Why is this so?

Comment: Before you ask "why", ask "if".

Comment: How many covalent bonds can N form with other elements?

Comment: There used to be a place on the internet where you could enter compounds and things such as acidity constants were calculated, including which proton deprotonated in which order. Alas, I can’t find the site any more.

Comment: What do you mean @IvanNeretin? It doesn't make sense to me since carboxylic acid groups are usually more acidic than amino groups in the examples I encounter, which is due to the electronegativity of the protic oxygen, resonance and inductive effects felt by the same oxygen atom. Then I see this hydrogen held by the amino groups getting deprotonated first before the other hydrogens held by the carboxylate groups, so I asked why.

Comment: I mean you should not blindly trust some random images brought to you by Google image search. Trust your logic; it is sound.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, okay, I added another reference that supports this ionization behavior of EDTA.

Answer (score 1):

Dissolved in water, EDTA can have net charges varying from -4 to +2, from fully deprotonated to all four carboxylic acid groups and two amine groups protonated.

It is the fully deprotonated form that binds to divalent cations (see e.g. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/81988/72973). If necessary, deprotonation occurs upon binding (see e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0301-4622(99)00047-2).

The intermediate protonation states occur as zwitterions both in aqueous solution and in some of the crystal forms. Disodium EDTA is an example:

[image]

Source: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/57339238#section=2D-Structure

> [OP] the hydrogens of these amino groups seem to be deprotonated first before those of the four carboxylic acid groups. Why is this so?

In aqueous solution, this carboxylic acid deprotonates before the ammonium. If you see other statements, they ignored to mention the prevalent tautomeric state. The situation in organic solvents might be different. The neutral species might have the carboxylic acid groups protonated and the amines deprotonated when EDTA is dissolved in a no-ionic organic solvent. The cationic or anionic species would probably not be soluble, so for those species, the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

The carboxylates deprotonate first followed by the amines.  The pKa values for the carboxylates ar 0.0, 1.5, 2.0, and 2.66.  The amines have pKa values of 6.16 and 10.24.  Ref. Harris.  Quantitative Chemical Analysis.

Comment: Yeah, that was wrong, I edited it now, but my question still stands.